# TextBox en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mi problema es que acabo de instalar el Visual Studio 2019 y lo estoy probando en un proyecto de aplicación de Windows Form. Estoy usando Visual Basic .NET y en el cuadro de herramientas donde me aparece para usar Button, CheckBox, Label, ect, no me aparece el TextBox.
Alguien sabe que puede suceder?

Gracias.

Comment: Seria excelente que subieras una captura del cuadro de herramientas.

Comment: Hola, ahi acabo de añadir una imagen del cuadro de herraminetas. Saludos.

Comment: Revisate este enlace: [Missing Text Box](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/190129/view.html), no es para vs2019 pero te puede servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias Orlando me ha sido de mucha ayuda ese enlace.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que Ingresar a la opcion de herramientas y despues elgir la opcion de elegir elementos del cuadro de texto y tienes que buscar que la opcion de textbox windows.form si no esta lo seleccionas y le das aceptar y eso seria todo